# ScreenRayCaster in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to reproduce this example https://www.kdab.com/new-in-qt-3d-5-11-generalized-ray-casting/

But when I add this line in my qml file

```
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
...
ScreenRayCaster {   id: screenRayCaster   }
```

I've got this error :

> ScreenRayCaster is not a type

My Qt version is 5.11 for vc2017 64bits.

Anyone knows how to use ScreenRayCaster in QML ?

Comment: try `import Qt3D.Render 2.11` instead. Also don't forget to add to your *.pro file the following: `QT += 3dcore 3drender 3dinput 3dquick 3dlogic qml quick 3dquickextras`, one of them, what you need

Comment: The doc says `import Qt3D.Render 2.0` so project dependencies are more likely

Comment: ok it works with 2.11